# Vagrantfile PHP v5.6 specified but v5.5 installed

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have a Vaprobash VagrantFile building a Ubuntu Nginx stack.

In it I specify PHP v5.6:

```
php_version = "5.6" //Options: 5.5 | 5.6
```

However, I run

```
$ vagrant up
```

when I ssh into the box and do

```
$ php -v
```

it shows PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37).

Why wasn't `5.6` installed?

Comment: Try rebuild your box

`vagrant destroy &&

vagrant up`

Comment: I'd tried $ vagrant reload --provision, but that rendered the same result.

Comment: vagrant destroy && vagrant up rendered the same result 
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/773692/14-04-cleanly-upgrade-to-ppaondrej-php-from-ppaondrej-php5-5-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this repo has been updated for php after the ppa has been migrated (see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php)

basically in `scripts/php.sh` you need to replace ppa by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

(make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` if you're running this command directly from the VM after the initial provisioning) -
and to install php5.6 you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install -qq libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

with this change, you now get

```
vagrant@vaprobash:~$ php -v
PHP 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

If you need additional php modules, make sure to replace the installation by specifying 5.6 in your php version such as

```
sudo apt-get install -qq php5.6-fpm
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.